# How can I remove the sitename or homepage title from all page titles?

Tags: customization

After switching to a different wordpress theme, Google started adding a sitename to ALL page titles in the search results.

E.g.:

> "Page title - Sitename"

Even when leaving the sitename area blank, Google still adds the homepage title next to every single page. This only started hapening after I switched to my new current wordpress theme.

I am using the Yoast SEO Plugin and even tried removing "%%sep%% %%sitename%%" in the settings, but still doesn't work.

I contacted the theme developer, this was his response:

> "The theme doesn't set any custom title. It uses default add_theme_support( 'title-tag' ); wordpress function and Seo by Yoast works with this."

How can I remove the sitename? Do I need to change the header.php code? If not which code should I edit?

Comment: Can you post a link to the current site, or copy and paste a snippet from the header.php showing <title>so that we can see more information?

Answer (score 7):

By default WordPress use `_wp_render_title_tag` to hook `wp_head` ( see [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L223) )

```
add_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );
```

This function is wrapper of [`wp_get_document_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_document_title/) to show title tag on theme if `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` added in theme file `functions.php` ( commonly ). 
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L944

If you see filter [`document_title_parts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/) on function [`wp_get_document_title()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L827), we can filter parameters that used in title ( `title`, `page`, `tagline`, `site` ).

Let say if we need to **remove site name title part of homepage and single post**, you just need to unset parameter `title` and `site` with [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), here the sample code ( add in `functions.php` theme file ):

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', function( $title )
{
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() )
        unset( $title['title'] ); /** Remove title name */

    if ( is_single() )
        unset( $title['site'] ); /** Remove site name */

    return $title;

}, 10, 1 );
```

About your issue in Google indexing, it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

In your header.php you may need to replace:

```
<title><?php whatever code you find in your existing theme ?></title>
```

with:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

Make sure you make a copy first so you can revert back if you need to!